# Apache Beam Combine.globally and outputting different type

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have a use case for batching multiple objects to be sent within one API request.

I am using Combine.globally() which forces me to have the same Output type as the Input type.

`org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine.globally(SerializableFunction<Iterable< MyClass >, MyClass > combiner)`

I would like to output a different type than my input and still batch my objects  - Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Could you use this one instead: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.39.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.html#globally-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.CombineFnBase.GlobalCombineFn-

Answer (score 0):

As [Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10687325/alexey-romanenko) had already menntioned in comments have to use `CombineFn`. Here the types of the input elements and the output elements can differ.

 From the documentation of [Advanced combinations using CombineFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine)

> For more complex combine functions, you can define a subclass ofCombineFn. You should use a CombineFn if the combine function requires a more sophisticated accumulator, must perform additional pre- or post-processing, might change the output type, or takes the key into account.

Example:
Declare your `FN` like below

```
public class CustomCombineFN extends CombineFn<MyInputClass, CustomCombineFN.Accum, MyOutputClass> {
       public class Accum {
           int sum = 0;
           int count = 0;
       }
       //override other methods and write your combine logic here
      //follow the documentation above mentioned for better understanding
 
   }
```

And in the pipeline you can do

```
pipeline.apply(Combine.globally(new CustomCombineFN()))
```